# SQL Server SqlClient strange exception of conversion

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, sqlclient

I have stored procedure. In its body I select some data, where one field is `nvarchar`, but it contains date (first 18 symbols are just text, but then its a date). Then I use condition where that date comparing with another date (already real date).

```
Select (bla bla) from (bla bla)
where DATEDIFF(DAY,DueDateDay,CAST(SUBSTRING(myField,18,10) as datetime)) < @dayCount
```

In SQL Server Management Studio this SP works great. BUT when I call this SP from my .NET app, using `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` it throws an exception:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

WHY??

SP:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UK_GetPlanningDetails_test] 
        @itemStart nvarchar(30),
        @itemEnd nvarchar(30), 
        @plan_codeStart nvarchar(3), 
        @plan_codeEnd nvarchar(3),
        @arrivalDelay bit,
        @demandDelay bit,
        @negativeCount bit,
        @arrivalMoveTo bit,
        @arrivalMoveFrom bit,
        @dayCount int,
        @noNeedArrival bit,
        @needAll bit,
        @negativeOnSKZ bit = 0
AS
BEGIN
    declare @sql nvarchar(2000);
    declare @sql2 nvarchar(2000);


    create table #temp
    (
        Item nvarchar(30),
        DueDateDay datetime, 
        description nvarchar(40), 
        plan_code nvarchar(3), 
        QtyOnHand nvarchar(40), 
        QtyReq nvarchar(40), 
        QtyRecv nvarchar(40),
        ExceptMessage nvarchar(2800), 
        MrpRef nvarchar(2800),
        LastChangedDate datetime
    )

    create table #temp2
    (
        Item nvarchar(30),
        DueDateDay datetime, 
        description nvarchar(40), 
        plan_code nvarchar(3), 
        QtyOnHand nvarchar(40), 
        QtyReq nvarchar(40), 
        QtyRecv nvarchar(40),
        ExceptMessage nvarchar(2800), 
        MrpRef nvarchar(2800),
        LastChangedDate datetime
    )

set @sql = N'SELECT o.Item, isnull(o.DueDateDay,''1950-01-01 00:00:00.000''), ISNULL(o.description,''''), isnull(o.plan_code,''''), convert(nvarchar(40),o.QtyOnHand), convert(nvarchar(40),o.QtyReq), convert(nvarchar(40),o.QtyRecv),isnull(o.ExceptMessage,''''), isnull(o.MrpRef,''''), isnull(o.LastChangedDate,''1950-01-01 00:00:00.000'')
  FROM [std_app].[dbo].[PlanningDetailsView] i
  left join [std_app].[dbo].[PlanningDetailsView] o on i.[Item]=o.[Item]
  where (i.ExceptMessage is not null)'

  if (@plan_codeStart<>'') set @sql=@sql+ ' and (i.[plan_code] >= '''+ @plan_codeStart+''')'
  if (@plan_codeEnd<>'') set @sql=@sql+ ' and (i.[plan_code] <= '''+ @plan_codeEnd+''')'
  if (@itemStart<>'') set @sql=@sql+ ' and (i.[Item] >= '''+ @itemStart+''')'
  if (@itemEnd<>'') set @sql=@sql+ ' and (i.[Item] <= '''+ @itemEnd+''')'

  if (@needAll<>1)
      begin 
      if(@negativeOnSKZ=0) set @sql = @sql + ' and (i.MrpRef not like (''TPLN  XFD-PLANT%'')) '
      set @sql =@sql + 'and ('

      if(@arrivalDelay<>0) set @sql = @sql + '(i.ExceptMessage like (''Задержка прогнозн.прихода%'')) or '
      if(@demandDelay<>0) set @sql = @sql + '(i.ExceptMessage like (''Задержка прогнозн.потребн.%'')) or '
      if(@negativeCount<>0) set @sql = @sql + '(i.ExceptMessage like (''Начал.колич.в наличии отрицательно%'')) or '
      if(@arrivalMoveTo<>0) set @sql = @sql + '(i.ExceptMessage like (''Перем.В Приход%'')) or '
      if(@noNeedArrival<>0) set @sql = @sql + '(i.ExceptMessage like (''Приход не требуется%'')) or '
      if(@negativeOnSKZ<>0) set @sql = @sql + '(i.MrpRef like (''TPLN  XFD-PLANT%'')) or '

      set @sql =@sql + '(i.ExceptMessage like('''')))'

          if(@arrivalMoveFrom<>0)
              begin
              set @sql2 = N'SELECT Item, isnull(DueDateDay,''1950-01-01 00:00:00.000''), ISNULL(description,''''), isnull(plan_code,''''), convert(nvarchar(40),QtyOnHand), convert(nvarchar(40),QtyReq), convert(nvarchar(40),QtyRecv),isnull(ExceptMessage,''''), isnull(MrpRef,''''), isnull(LastChangedDate,''1950-01-01 00:00:00.000'')
              FROM [std_app].[dbo].[PlanningDetailsView]
              where (ExceptMessage is not null) 
              and (ExceptMessage like (''Перем.из прихода%''))'

                if (@plan_codeStart<>'') set @sql2=@sql2+ ' and ([plan_code] >= '''+ @plan_codeStart+''')'
                if (@plan_codeEnd<>'') set @sql2=@sql2+ ' and ([plan_code] <= '''+ @plan_codeEnd+''')'
                if (@itemStart<>'') set @sql2=@sql2+ ' and ([Item] >= '''+ @itemStart+''')'
                if (@itemEnd<>'') set @sql2=@sql2+ ' and ([Item] <= '''+ @itemEnd+''')'

              insert into #temp2 execute(@sql2)
              if(@dayCount>0)
                   begin
                   delete from #temp2 where DATEDIFF(DAY,DueDateDay,CAST(SUBSTRING(ExceptMessage,18,10) as datetime))<@dayCount
                   end
              end
      end

  insert into #temp execute(@sql)

  select my.*, StartDate = isnull(their.StartDate,'1950-01-01 00:00:00.000') from (select Item, DueDateDay, description, plan_code, QtyOnHand, QtyReq, QtyRecv, ExceptMessage, MrpRef, LastChangedDate from #temp
  union
  (
  select o.Item, o.DueDate, o.description, o.plan_code, o.QtyOnHand, o.QtyReq, o.QtyRecv, o.ExceptMessage, o.MrpRef, o.LastChangedDate 
  from #temp2 i left join [std_App].dbo.PlanningDetailsView o on i.Item = o.Item 
  )) my 
  left join (   select
   --- Four part key -----------------------
   --- Check performance before changing ---
     apsplan.item as Item
   , apsplan.due_date_day as DueDateDay
   , 0 as QtyOnHand
   , case when is_demand = 1 then apsplan.qty else 0 end as QtyReq
   , case when is_demand = 1 then 0 else apsplan.qty end as QtyRecv
   , case
        when is_demand = 1
        then  case
                 when apsplan.ref_type = 'S'
                 then dbo.PPSRef(apsplan.ref_num, isnull(apsplan.ref_line_suf,0))
                 else
                    case
                       WHEN apsplan.xref_num IS NOT NULL
                       THEN 'X'
                       ELSE ''
                    END +
                    CASE apsplan.ref_type
                       WHEN 'N' THEN 'PPLN  '
                       WHEN 'D' THEN 'TPLN  '
                       WHEN 'J' THEN 'PJOB  '
                       WHEN 'M' THEN 'PMPS  '
                       WHEN 'S' THEN 'PPS   '
                       WHEN 'C' THEN 'CO    '
                       ELSE ''
                    END +
                    CASE
                       WHEN apsplan.ref_num IS NOT NULL
                       THEN apsplan.ref_num
                       ELSE ''
                    END +
                    CASE
                       WHEN apsplan.ref_line_suf IS NOT NULL
                       THEN '-' + CAST(apsplan.ref_line_suf AS CHAR(4))
                       ELSE ''
                    END +
                    CASE
                       WHEN apsplan.ref_rel IS NOT NULL
                       THEN '-' + SUBSTRING('000' + CAST(apsplan.ref_rel AS NVARCHAR),
                               LEN('000' + CAST(apsplan.ref_rel AS NVARCHAR)) -3, 4)
ELSE ''
                    END
              end
        else 'PLN   ' + apsplan.ref_num -- ORDER000.ORDERID
     end
     as MrpRef
   , NULL as MrpExcept --dbo.GetMrpExcMesg(apsplan.item, apsplan.ref_type, apsplan.ref_num, apsplan.ref_line_suf, apsplan.ref_rel)
   , apsplan.start_date as StartDate
   FROM (
      select *
         ,due_date as EndDate
         ,ISNULL((select mp.ENDDATE
                   from apsplandetail
                   join MATLPLAN000 mp on mp.MATLTAG = apsplandetail.matltag and mp.PMATLTAG = 0
                   join ORDER000 o on o.ORDERID = mp.ORDERID and o.ORDTYPE = 310 -- Safety stock
                   where apsplan.RowPointer = apsplandetail.apsplan_reference), apsplan.due_date)
          as ProjectedDate
      from apsplan with(index(IX_apsplan_item_due_date_day))
      where apsplan.is_demand = 1 and apsplan.qty != 0

      union all

      select *
         ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(apsplan.ref_num,1,3) = 'ROP' THEN apsplan.due_date
               ELSE ISNULL ((select mp.NEEDDATE
                              from MATLPLAN000 mp
                              join ORDER000 o on o.ORDERID = mp.ORDERID and o.ORDTYPE = 310 -- Safety stock
                              where mp.MATLTAG = apsplan.ref_num and mp.PMATLTAG = 0), apsplan.due_date)
               END as EndDate
         ,due_date as ProjectedDate
      from apsplan with(index(IX_apsplan_item_due_date_day))
      where apsplan.is_demand = 0 and apsplan.ref_type <> 'Z'
   ) apsplan) their on their.Item=my.Item and my.MrpRef=their.MrpRef

  where my.MrpRef not like case when @negativeOnSKZ=0 then ('TPLN  XFD-PLANT%') else ('some unreal data') end or my.MrpRef like case when @negativeOnSKZ=1 then ('TPLN  XFD-PLANT%') else ('some unreal data') end
  order by my.item,my.DueDateDay



  END
```

CALL:

```
public static DataTable getTable(string connectionString, string SQLcommand)
{
        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        Con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(SQLcommand, Con);
        cmd1.CommandTimeout = 5 * 60 * 1000;
        SqlDataReader Read1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable getTab = new DataTable();
        getTab.Load(Read1);
        Con.Close();
        return getTab;
}

SQLcommand = EXEC [dbo].[UK_GetPlanningDetails_test] @itemStart = N'', @itemEnd = N'', @plan_codeStart = N'', @plan_codeEnd = N'', @arrivalDelay = 0 , @demandDelay = 0 , @negativeCount = 0 , @arrivalMoveTo = 0 , @arrivalMoveFrom = 1 , @dayCount = 10 , @noNeedArrival = 0 , @needAll = 0 , @negativeOnSKZ = 0
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the CAST in the procedure that's causing the conversion failure? Do you have any parameters passed into the procedure?

Comment: it is the only place in that proc, where conversion used
more than that it WORKS with the same params from msqsqlsms

Comment: Could you please show us your stored procedure, as well as the code calling it?

Comment: oh... ok ill try, but it is really big)

Comment: You can get a conversion error when you pass in what you think is a date to a proc which is why I asked about parameters. Equally if you manipulate values within the proc there can be other sources of conversion failure

Comment: I would try to make it an **actual call** to the stored procedure! Pass the stored proc name to `SqlCommand`, set its '.CommandType` to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`, and define the parameters (names, datatypes, values) and then call that stored proc like that - don't use the `EXEC .....` method

Comment: yes, actual call was helpfull thx!)

Comment: what is the value in the exceptMessage?

Answer (score 0):

I think the date format in string is not proper. the reason of works in SQL Server Management Studio and not works in .Net can be the connections languge.

first select works but secend gives same exeption

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english
select CAST('12.18.2012' as datetime)

SET LANGUAGE turkish
select CAST('12.18.2012' as datetime)
```